# Click all google AdSense block buttons at once?

Tags: javascript, toggle, adsense

Hello guys can anyone help with a script or trick to click all AdSense Block buttons at once

[image]

I used this one but it took to much time
setInterval(function(){
toggl=document.querySelector('.all-networks-table div.material-toggle[aria-pressed=false]');
if (toggl==null){document.querySelector('.all-networks-table material-button.next').click()}else{toggl.click()}
}, 1000);

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
var toggl;
setInterval(function(){
    toggl=document.querySelector('.all-networks-table div.material-toggle[aria-checked=false]');
    if (toggl==null){
        document.querySelector('.all-networks-table material-button.next').click()
    }else{
        toggl.click()
    }
}, 100);
```